# New Item of List View

Tags: web-part, list-view

I created a webpart. The webpart is a slider. I add new item on the webpart's list.

I want to I add my final list of items in that it appears at the top. So get the slider of the first image. How can I do this?

My webpart code:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="False" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="False" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" ViewGuid="{1267E2D3-4EB4-4AFA-A14F-9D2521574A4E}" EnableOriginalValue="False" ViewContentTypeId="" ListName="{9154D3E4-9E00-4C0A-A4D9-EB4DBF6C3CC6}" ListId="9154d3e4-9e00-4c0a-a4d9-eb4dbf6c3cc6" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="Duyuru" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="wpz" PartOrder="1" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png?rev=23" TitleUrl="/Lists/Duyuru" DetailLink="/Lists/Duyuru" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png?rev=23" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_a6ca49f2_9eb5_4859_b170_4fe610578367" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="NonSensitiveData" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{1267E2D3-4EB4-4AFA-A14F-9D2521574A4E}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>







<ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection" /><ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection" /><ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue="" /><ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection" /><ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" /><ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" /><ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" /><ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" /></ParameterBindings>
<Xsl>














<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">

    <xsl:output method='html' indent='yes'/>

    <xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse' xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">

        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide  bt-nav-mar" data-ride="carousel"> 

        <div class="carousel-inner">          
            <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>

        </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
            </a> 
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
            </a>    

    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='Row'>
         <div class="item" id="xslide"> 
         <a href="/Lists/Duyuru/DispForm.aspx?ID={string(@ID)}"  class="fontText">

            <img><xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Resim"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute></img>
            </a>
         </div>

     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

</Xsl>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<XmlDefinition>
<View Name="{1267E2D3-4EB4-4AFA-A14F-9D2521574A4E}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="/SitePages/Home.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" ><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID"/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/><FieldRef Name="Resim"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

Comment: Is this a custom webpart? While displaying items can't you use modified desc order by clause?

Comment: How can I add the clause? Is it In the list settings? @Amal

Comment: If its CAML query then you can use ORDER BY `Ascending = False`

Comment: @Amal I updated my questions. I added my xsl code. Should I add order by clause in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated question. You can change the following

```
<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID"/></OrderBy></Query>
```

To

```
<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending = "False"/></OrderBy></Query>
```